# Python pandas series - how can I print only the value without the other information

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have a Python series that gives me the following:

```
df_1974.loc[[df_1974["Close*"].idxmin()]]['date_final']

type(df_1974.loc[[df_1974["Close*"].idxmin()]]['date_final'])

df_1974.loc[[df_1974["Close*"].idxmin()]]['date_final']
Out[8]: 
12099   1974-10-03
Name: date_final, dtype: datetime64[ns]

type(df_1974.loc[[df_1974["Close*"].idxmin()]]['date_final'])
Out[9]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

How can I print only the value 1974-10-03 without the other information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert this `to_numpy()` or `to_list()` or `values` and print the 0th element. e.g.,

```
>>> df_1974.loc[[df_1974["Close*"].idxmin()]]['date_final'].astype("str").to_list()[0]
>>> '1974-10-03'
```

Comment: I get this `df_1974.loc[[df_1974["Close*"].idxmin()]]['date_final'].to_list()[0]
Out[18]: Timestamp('1974-10-03 00:00:00')` while I only want the value

Comment: Just get the column as `str`. Updated the solution.

Answer (score 0):

use `df_1974.loc[[df_1974["Close*"].idxmin()]]['date_final'].values` which returns an array from pandas series and select the first element if there is only one element in the data/series.